Why do I need a generic Locals type Request in express?
I thought I had found a way to create the properties of a Request object without the need for global declarations, but a problem arose.
I tried to use the generic Locals for Request to create the req.auth property, but it returned an error and now I have a question about what this generic is needed for. Here is an example:
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

interface Local {
  auth: {
    token: string;
    payload: Object;
  }
}

const example = function (req: Request<{}, {}, {}, {}, Local>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  req.auth
  next();
};


You can try to create a interface to extends Request instead of passing the interface to Request.
interface Local extends Request {
  auth: {
    token: string;
    payload: Object;
  };
}


const example = function (req: Local, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  req.auth;
  next();
};

If you hover the Request type, you can see that the fifth type is Locals extends Record<string, any> which this type will be used for res.locals, not req

